# Image in ImageIcon does not show in Linux, but it does in Windows

Tags: java, swing

When I open it in windows, all the images are perfectly seen, but when I open it in Linux, only the blank window is seen. I think it's because of the paths. It should be noted that I am trying to access an image that is in a package called "img". what's the problem?. This happens when the project is already packaged.

```
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/image.png")));
```

Comment: When I open it in windows, all the images are perfectly seen, but when I open it in Linux, only the blank window is seen

Comment: Please see [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. Also note that already the wording is confusing. Linux is an operating system, java is a programming language. Most likely, the answer is for you to step back, and read a basic tutorial regarding the specific topic you intend to achieve. And please note: do note give additional information in comments. Edit/Update your question instead.

Comment: Could be related with directory separator. As windows you use `/` and linux is `\`. Check the environment variable/constant related with directory separator.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make it work in both Linux and Windows, you need to do the following:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("/img/image.png"))));
```

actually what matters is this:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit (). getImage (getClass (). getResource ("/ img / image.png")).
```

It worked perfectly for me